# Kotlin CallbackFlow - Is it possible for awaitClose to be called before rest of block is run?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Looking at the callbackFlow docs I see..

> ```
> The callback register/unregister methods provided by an external API must be thread-safe, because awaitClose block can be called at any time due to asynchronous nature of cancellation, even concurrently with the call of the callback.
> ```

Does this mean that awaitClose could be called before the rest of the callbackFlow finishes? I am seeing a NPE in production where it appears the `awaitClose` block is being called while the `start()` function above it in the block is still running.

This code is converting the Android Animator.AnimatorListener to a callbackFlow and attempting to remove the listeners and cancel the animation when the flows job is cancelled or the animation ends or is cancelled. I am seeing a NPE only in production, but specifically relating to the listeners being removed somehow while the `start()` function is still running, which seems like it should be impossible since the `awaitClose` line should have to be hit before recognizing cancellation and by then `start()` would have been completed.

```
EX.
callbackFlow {
    val eventListener = object : Animator.AnimatorListener {
        override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator) {
            // No-op
        }

        override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
            trySendBlocking(AnimationEvent.End)
            close()
        }

        override fun onAnimationCancel(animation: Animator) {
            trySendBlocking(AnimationEvent.Cancelled)
            close()
        }

        override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animator) {
            trySendBlocking(AnimationEvent.Repeat)
        }
    }

    addListener(listener)

    start() // Somehow awaitClose is being called while this function is still running

    awaitClose {
        removeAllListeners()
        cancel()
    }
}
```